# Generic function that receives different view models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using MVC 2.

I have 5 view models and each has different message properties that i need to populate from the DB. The property names are different, per the message type.

In the view models, i have type available, for which i need to pull the messages.

If the type is Welcome, then i want to pull the 3 welcome messages.

I want to write a generic function that i will call from each action. This generic function will then look at the object being passed and its type property and then will fill the message properties specified in this view model. **How can i accomplish this?** From my actions, i don't want to call a separate function for each messages type.

I am trying to do some thing like following:

```
public void GetMessage(object viewModel, bool isCheckMessages)
        {
            viewModel = (AnnualReportWelComeViewModel)viewModel;

        }
```

But the viewModel in this instance is not picking properties specified in AnnualReportWelComeViewModel.

Am i thinking straight here or just making it way over complicated than it needs to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are reusing same variable when converting types. Your `viewModel` is of type `object` and even if you try to convert it to another type you will still see it as `object`. You should try something along these lines:

```
public void GetMessage(object viewModel, bool isCheckMessages)
{
  var reportMessage = viewModel as AnnualReportWelComeViewModel;
  if (reportMessage != null)
  {
    // viewModel passed was of type AnnualReportWelComeViewModel
  }
}
```

If you want this function to check for many possible types of `viewModel` then you could do something like:

```
public void GetMessage(object viewModel, bool isCheckMessages)
{
  if (viewModel is AnnualReportWelComeViewModel)
  {
     var reportMessage = viewModel as AnnualReportWelComeViewModel;
     // ...
  }
  else if (viewModel is MonthlyReportWelComeViewModel)
  {
     var reportMessage = viewModel as MonthlyReportWelComeViewModel;
     // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this for a little while now.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I totally agree with you but a - this is the answer OP was looking for and b - redesigning it would require much more effort than just changing a single method

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, Ramunas is correct since we are on a deadline and can't change much (upgrade). I am still making it much better wherever i can, without investing too much into upgrading original functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should create interface IViewModelWithMessage and inherit all your viewmodel from it.

```
public interface IViewModelWithMessage
{
    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In your viewmodels you should map inherited property Message to this model messages:

```
public class AnnualReportWelComeViewModel : IViewModelWithMessage
{
    public string ViewModelMessage { get; set; }
    ....
    string IViewModelWithMessage.Message {
        get { return ViewModelMessage; }
        set { ViewModelMessage = value; }
    }
}
```

Do what you want with Message property of interface and this value will be passed to other properties.

```
public void GetMessage(IViewModelWithMessage viewModel, bool isCheckMessages)
{
    ...
    viewmodel.Message = ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i have gone with below example at this time. I am going to keep your solution handy and will try to build a pilot to test it out.